# Take 1D slice between two points in 2D MATLAB array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying to write a function that given 2 points in a `2D MATLAB` array will return a `1D array` of the elements connecting the points.

So `arr=[1 2 3 4 5;6 7 8 9 10;11 12  13 14 15;16 17 18 19 20;21 22 23 24 25 ]`

and the points between `arr(4,2)` and `arr(1,5)` would be returned as `[17 13 9 5`].

For example, although I'm fine with points being interpolated if required.

If it helps this is how I do it in Python

```
length = int(np.hypot(x1-x0, y1-y0))
xx, yy = np.linspace(x0, x1, length), np.linspace(y0, y1, length)
zi = arr[xx.astype(np.int), yy.astype(np.int)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`interp2`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html):

lets say we'd like to sample 20 evenly space points from `(1.3, 2.4)` to `(4.6, 3.5)`

```
arr=[ 1  2  3  4  5;
      6  7  8  9 10;
     11 12 13 14 15;
     16 17 18 19 20;
     21 22 23 24 25 ]

[x, y] = meshgrid(1:5,1:5)
xx = linspace (1.3, 4.6, 20)
yy = linspace (2.4, 3.5, 20)
interp2(x,y,arr, xx,yy)
```

gives:

```
 8.30000000000000
 8.76315789473684
 9.22631578947368
 9.68947368421053
10.15263157894737
10.61578947368421
11.07894736842105
11.54210526315790
12.00526315789474
12.46842105263158
12.93157894736842
13.39473684210526
13.85789473684211
14.32105263157895
14.78421052631579
15.24736842105263
15.71052631578947
16.17368421052632
16.63684210526316
17.10000000000000
```

You can see how the line follows your mesh:

```
mesh(x,y,arr)
hold on
plot3(xx,yy,interp2(x,y,arr, xx,yy))
```

[image]